# Customize OpenIddict route/endpoint matching

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, openiddict

How does one customize the endpoint/route detection in OpenIddict 5.0? For example, if I wanted to listen on multiple token endpoints or to look inside the request data before matching?

In 3.x it was [apparently possible](https://kevinchalet.com/2018/07/02/implementing-advanced-scenarios-using-the-new-openiddict-rc3-events-model/) to do this:

```cs
options.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.MatchEndpoint>(notification =>
```

But in 5.x the `OpenIddictServerEvents.MatchEndpoint` event does not exist anymore and I cannot find a similar one. What is the new approach to this?